# Как запускать проект JetBrains в cmd?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, jetbrains, rider

Помогите пожалуйста, как мне в среде **JetBrains** запустить проект в командной строке? Типо, в **JetBrains** запускается проект во встроенной командной строке, а вот надо, чтобы было как в **Visual Studio** - запускаешь код, он запускается в **cmd.exe**. Можно ли также настроить и для **JetBrains**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно просто поменять интерпретатор на `cmd.exe /c` либо на `start`. Тогда будет запускаться в отдельном окне.

То есть, если у вас стоит запуск, например, `C:\test.exe`, вам надо заменить на строку `cmd.exe /c "C:\test.exe"`.

Или как вариант поставить чуть ниже галочку на **Use External Console**.

[image: Диалог запуска]

Comment: Где его поменять?

Comment: Смотрите, мне помог второй вариант, а вот первый пишет ошибку: `Invalid exe path: cmd.exe /c "C:/Users/Ктото/RiderProjects/ConsoleApplication1/bin/Debug/ConsoleApplication1.exe"`

Comment: @A_Br2H ну у меня не было под рукой компьютера Windows, я подозреваю, что надо было указать полный путь к `cmd.exe` - `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`, а параметры `/c "C:/Users/Ктото/RiderProjects/ConsoleApplication1/bin/Debug/ConsoleApplication1.exe"` вписать строкой ниже.
В любом случае, этот метод работает не только в IDE от JetBrains, запуск `cmd /c C:\path\to\app.exe` работает почти везде, где есть возможность выполнить команду.